# Azure Pipeline Unit Test Code Coverage RunSettings Using xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xunit

I have a solution with multiple unit tests projects.

So the goal here is to exclude the **Migrations** folder

I have added a runsettings file named **.runsettings** in the root of the test project

```
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <Format>json,cobertura,lcov,teamcity,opencover</Format>          
          <Exclude>[*]stackoverflow.Infrastructure.Migrations*</Exclude> 
          <IncludeTestAssembly>false</IncludeTestAssembly>
          <DeterministicReport>false</DeterministicReport>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

We have referenced the runsettings file like this in the azure-pipelines.yml:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--collect "XPlat Code Coverage" --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --settings $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\Tests\stackoverflow.Infrastructure.Tests\.runsettings'
```

after doing this now the coverage results disapeared!

[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this? I was having similar issues and after I added the CodeCoverage block and excluding ModulePath it did work.

```
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>
                        <ModulePaths>
                            <Exclude>
                                <ModulePath>.*stackoverflow.Infrastructure.Migrations.*</ModulePath>
                            </Exclude>
                        </ModulePaths>
                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For me the issue was I tried to use Include and for whatever reason dlls werent found. But the sample provided here should work